# what is the function of "JacksonInitializer" in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I find code in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer`:

```
runSafely(new JacksonInitializer());

private static class JacksonInitializer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build();
    }

}
```

It seems that `ObjectMapper` built here is dropped, so what is the function of this code?

Thanks!